# Google Charts using JSON (without Webserver!)

Tags: html, json, perl, charts

So I want to create a chart using Google Chart API. The problem is following:
I need to create a chart which would use JSON data for the Output.
Example:

I am creating a BarChart which should show Montly Income. Each bar should represent X value of income. But this income changes monthly and I dont want to update the new numbers (as there are plenty) manually by writting them inside the JSON structure (I will use PERL scripts that will gather the new data).

I have read plenty on ther web, but all are using JSON COMBINED WITH PHP ! But I do not have a Web Server. What I want is to create a JSON FOLDER on my desktop, which will contain 100 JSON files inside it. 
And when I browse my HTML page, I will click on Monthly Income (May) and this should open a new HTML page which should have some sort of INCLUDE or call function, which should call a SPECIFIC JSON file from the JSON folder on my computer that is coresponded with the path I have chosen on my webpage (in this case Monthly income (May)).

I think my problem is MORE SIMPLE than the method with PHP updating, because I am not worried with the updates - I will update my text files with PERL script. I just need a way, how to include a JSON file into my HTML script, without using PHP or any of these WEB SERVER related stuff.

Any ideas / suggestion ?

Thanks,
David

Comment: *"...I need to create a chart which would use JSON data for the Output."* You mean input, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably do it cross-browser with JSON because some browsers block ajax calls from local files (e.g., `file://` URLs). But you can do it with JSON-P.

You create the files like this:

```
dataCallback(/*...JSON here...*/)
```

E.g.:

```
dataCallback({
    "foo": "bar"
});
```

...and use this to load the relevant:

```
<script>
function dataCallback(data) {
    // Here, the data will be the deserialized (parsed) data
}
</script>
<script src="/path/to/jsonp/file"></script>
```

Basically this is using JavaScript, rather than JSON, but where the data file although technically code is really just a function call with the data in the argument.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So in the :
function dataCallback(data) {// Do I write here the inpute values for the chart?}

And then in drawChart function I use: drawChart(data)  ?

Comment: @user3533253: Right. I mean, you could put make the "data" files use `drawChart(/*...JSON here...*/)` directly.

Comment: Hello, I need abit more assistance at this. I am stuck  with the part:
function dataCallback (data) {
// What to write here?}

Because I already declared my INPUTS in the dataCallback ({
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
})

in here. So I dont know what to write inside the function.

Comment: @user3533253: You write the code to use the data. As I said above, if all you're going to do with the data is call `drawChart`, you could use that directly. Or if you prefer to keep them separate, then `function dataCallback(data) { drawChart(data); }`

Comment: I understand, but I still have a problem with the coding it seems.
This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x5eua/

And this is the basic example of BarChart coding:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

I am not sure if I am using the dataCallback function correctly.
You are very helpfull, but I am quite new to the HTML / JS programming, so I apologize if I am making really bad mistakes or dont understand some things.

Comment: @user3533253: Sorry, but I suggest going through some fundamental JavaScript tutorials before returning to your current task, as that code has quite basic syntax errors in it.